# Amazon S3 and .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, amazon-s3, iweb

I have a site (Made in iWeb) that I am hosting on Amazon S3. I am trying to get `www.domain.com/Apps/Physics.html` to turn into `www.domain.com/Apps/Physics`.

I am trying to accomplish this with an .htaccess file. The file is stored in the root of the bucket (where the index.html file is). Here's the problem: It doesn't work. Still can't use `www.domain.com/Apps/Physics`.

I have a GoDaddy domain, hosted on the S3 server. Does this help?

Comment: Somehow I doubt Amazon S3 uses Apache to serve your files (.htaccess isn't part of any standard - it's an Apache-specific feature)

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I was thinking the same thing... There still has to be a way to do it, though...

Comment: The service does describe itself a "simple storage service" so I wouldn't be surprised if they didn't have features that are commonly used for running websites instead of plain data storage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

S3 is a content server and **not** a web server. You may want to try renting a small [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance with Apache to do what you want.

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you add CNAME record 'static' for domain.com (this one for S3) and host www on a Apache server and a rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^somefolder/(.*)$ http://static.domain.com/$1 [P]
```

OR

```
#This will save your time of creating the additional CNAME step    
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^somefolder/(.*)$ http://yourbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/$1 [P]
```

**EDIT**: Using mod proxy seems to be a better option.

Comment: What would this rule do exactly? How would a request for `static.domain.com` (which this is presumably looking for) end up on the Apache server in the first place?

Comment: Proxying everything via your server nullifies some of the benefits of using S3 in the first place. Besides, this person has a static website, setting up a reverse proxy configuration just to serve some files from S3 is overkill.

Comment: Agreed. I don't see any other way to achieve this. If he desperately wants this: it is the workaround. :)

Answer (score 7):

Anno 2016 Amazon S3 [supports redirects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html).

Comment: Still doesn't accomplish exactly what I wanted, but it's much closer.

Comment: Limit of 50 redirects though which could be an issue

Comment: We have used "Redirect requests for an object" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html#redirect-requests-object-metadata that help you circumvent the 50 limit. Just an empty file of the same name with the metadata `x-amz-website-redirect-location` set to the desired destination. It's not ultra-flexible, but does work.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon S3 only serves static content.

To request an user and a password you need to use a "middle" application like [s3auth](https://github.com/yegor256/s3auth).

You can install in your own server or use their online solution [here](http://www.s3auth.com).

Answer (score 1):

1. Set your S3 bucket as a Static Host
2. Create a CloudFront distribution
3. Ensure your Origin is the address of the S3 static host and not the S3 bucket *important
4. Serve you page as index.html in the folder Physics