# Serve Static Pages from S3 using Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I'm planning to build a Django app to generate and later server static pages (probably stored on S3). When users visit a url like mysite.com/static-pages/12345 the static file in my S3 bucket named 12345.html should be served. That static file might be the static html page of a blog page my site has generated for the user, for example.

This is *different* from including static resources like CSS/Javascript files on a page that is rendered as a Django template since I already know how to use Django templates and SQL databases - what's unfamiliar to me is that my "data" is now a file on S3 rather than an entry in a database AND that I don't actually need to use a template.

**How exactly can I retrieve the requested data (i.e. a static page) and return it to the user?** I'd like to minimize performance penalties within reason, although of course it would be fastest if users directly requested their static pages from S3 (I don't want them to do this)".

A few additional questions:
I've read elsewhere about a django flatpages app which stores html pages in a database, but it seems like static html pages are best stored on a filesystem like S3, no?
Is there a way to have the request come in to my Django application and have S3 serve the file directly while making it appear to have come from my application (i.e. the browser url still says mysite.com/static-pages/12345, but the page did not go through my Django server)?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 doesn't support URL rewriting (it's not a webserver), so you're going to have no choice but to proxy the requests to a web server or service that can rewrite the urls for you.

You could use a web server you control and follow the [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14095923/808532) to have apache rewrite the URLs, but that seems somewhat wasteful when the whole point is loading a static website.

Alternatively, I have a solution that might work if you want to stay purely in S3:

You have the option to specify an HTML document that will be returned to the user's browser in the case of 404 - the error document. You could create a tiny HTML page that checked to the current URL, and simply changed window.location to go to "rewritten" url without the `.html` extension:

```
<html>
<script>
    var slash = window.location.lastIndexOf("/");
    var dot = window.location.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (slash < dot) && (dot != -1) {
        window.location = window.location + ".html";
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Obviously you'd want to make it more robust, but you get the idea.

The downside is that each request for your static pages using the url will make an extra round-trip from the user's browser to your server (once for the 404 page, and then once to get the real page).

Also, you'd need to adjust my above code to avoid triggering a 404 loop in the case of an actual url being incorrect by adding a check something like:

```
var loopcheck = window.location.IndexOf(".html");
if (lookcheck != -1) {
    window.location = "real404.html";
    return;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create index.html inside /static-pages/12345/ folder and it will be served.