# How to add rel canonical in Amazon AWS S3 to a pdf file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, seo, canonical-link

I have one page that has one pdf on it, with the same content. The pdf is served from Amazon AWS S3, how can I add the rel canonical to the S3 to avoid duplicate content?
thanks!

EDIT

And with cloudfront can I do this?

Comment: If you have "one" page with "one" pdf, what or where is the "duplicate" content? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Yes, some of the content of the page is in the pdf too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You’d have to send the HTTP header `Link` when delivering the PDF:

```
Link: <http://example.com/your-canonical-page>; rel="canonical"
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-5

*Amazon S3* seems to offer static content hosting only, so there is no way to set this header.

Comment: How can I do this with Amazon S3? Thanks!

Comment: @user1763732: If *Amazon S3* doesn’t support any kind of programming language (e.g., PHP) or `.htaccess` or similar ([which doesn’t seem so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14095879/1591669)), you can’t.