# htaccess rewrite rule for images to be served in webp from CDN

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, amazon-s3, webp

Am serving my images from S3 bucket which has cname "cdn"

I uploaded webp copy of my images and trying to rewrite the path with htaccess

currently all my images are under the subdomain cdn.mydomain.com

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn.mydomain.com$/wp-content/uploads-webpc/$1.jpg.webp -f
RewriteRule wp-content/uploads/(.+)\.jpg$ wp-content/uploads-webpc/$1.jpg.webp [T=image/w
ebp]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The value you are trying to check `%{HTTP_HOST}` against there, is not a host name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my images from S3 bucket which has cname "cdn"

If by this you mean you have a DNS CNAME `cdn` that is pointing directly at your Amazon S3 bucket then this method is unlikely to work since S3 is simply a static storage solution and does not provide such features as Apache/`.htaccess` AFAIK.

See here: [Amazon S3 and .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095818/amazon-s3-and-htaccess)

The remainder of my answer is assuming the `cdn` CNAME is pointing at your application/Apache server (where the `.webp` images are also located/duplicated if you want to check the existence of these files before proxying the request) and you are later proxying the request to your Amazon S3 bucket, although this somewhat defeats the point in having a CDN in the first place.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn.mydomain.com$/wp-content/uploads-webpc/$1.jpg.webp -f
> RewriteRule wp-content/uploads/(.+)\.jpg$ wp-content/uploads-webpc/$1.jpg.webp [T=image/webp]
> ```

The second *condition* that is supposedly checking against the HTTP `Host` header is entirely invalid and you would expect to generate a 500 Internal Server Error response (due to "bad flag delimiters"). The `Host` header contains the hostname only, eg. `cdn.mydomain.com`, not the URL-path (although the regex would also be invalid). And to check the existence of the target file you need another/separate *condition*. (If the CNAME was pointing directly at the S3 bucket then this check is arguably superfluous anyway since aren't all requests received to this same hostname?)

You are also missing the start-of-string anchor (ie. `^`) on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, so this creates a many to one rewrite (potentially a duplicate content issue) as it will rewrite `/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg` and `/foo/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg` to the same target URL, namely `wp-content/uploads-webpc/image.jpg.webp`.

You are missing the `L` (`last`) flag on the `RewriteRule`. An issue if you have other directives.

You could also capture more elements of the requested URL-path to save repetition in the *substitution* string.

Assuming you are intending to rewrite the request from `/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg` to `/wp-content/uploads-webpc/image.jpg.webp` then try the following instead, bringing the above points together:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/uploads-webpc/$1.jpg.webp -f
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads)/([^./]+\.jpg)$ $1-webpc/$2.webp [T=image/webp,L]
```

Note that the `$1` backreference simply captures the `wp-content/uploads` part of the requested URL-path, so save repeitition. And the `$2` backreference now captures the `.jpg` file extension as well.

Comment: Thank you! According to your answer .htaccess won't be the solution for my case. I'll try to figure out alternative solution.

For now am temporarily using two plugins which are doing the job together "WP Offload Media" & "EWWW Image Optimizer".